# How do I create a texture from this image so that black is ignored but white is applied on whatever?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Illustrator 2018 
Windows.

I want to apply the distressing in the image below onto a logo (black and white) and from tutorials it seems creating a texture seems the way to go.

What I want is the black part of the below image to be ignored or transparent but the white parts to be applied to what ever object I choose (in this case the black and white logo).

What I am trying to do is add printer noise (speckles & lines) to the logo.

How do I do this?

[image: Noise example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BW image as an Opacity Mask for your logo. White=as is, Black=full transparent

[image]

Place the BW image above your logo (=Group), select all and select "Make Opacity Mask", it's in the transparency panel.